# Zabbix 3.4.2 - how to add {HOST.NAME} to discovered items

Tags: zabbix

Since every trigger in OS Template Linux have already {HOST.NAME} added to the trigger name except items from discovery (ex. disc volumes) I wonder if there is a way to add {HOST.NAME} to all discovered items so zabbix can produce email alerts like:

OK: Free disk space on {HOST.NAME} is less than 20% on volume /app1
instead of:

OK: Free disk space is less than 20% on volume /app1

Kind Regards,

Zabbix 3.4.2

Comment: Can you not use `trigger protypes` with `{HOST.NAME}` in `name` ? It should give the desired results.

Comment: Hi Vishwaraj, I've added {HOST.NAME} to the trigger prototype. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Adding {HOST.NAME} to the template via via the:

Configuration -> Template -> Discovery rule -> Trigger prototype

works

Answer (score -1):

Try this: OK: Free disk space on {HOST.NAME**1**} is less than 20% on volume /app1

I change {HOST.NAME} to {HOST.NAME1}